# Galleria Jquery Transition Effects

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, galleria

So I am using galleria to show a slide show. I have it set to autoplay, so it shows a new picture every 3 seconds. Currently, the transition seems to be the picture sliding in from the right. Is there a way I can have it fade in? Pretty much any transition other then the sliding.

Thanks!
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

The [default transition is `'fade'`](http://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/master/docs/options.rst), but if you're loading a theme this may not be the case, since most themes change the default, just set the [`transition` option](http://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/master/docs/options.rst) back to "fade", like this:

```
Galleria.loadTheme('/themes/classic/galleria.classic.js'); //loading theme
$('#demo').galleria({
    height:400,
    transition: 'fade'
});
```